# Python 3: go back to start of if statement if string longer than

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, compare

I'm very new to python and code in general and I'm wondering how i can do something like this:

User enters string, computer checks if string is longer then 10 characters and if it is it asks for the user to enter a new string. This is what i have right now.

```
usernamelength = (len(username))
if usernamelength > 10:
    return
else:
    print("Hello, %s. Placeholder text." %username)
```

Sorry if i'm missing out something obvious, as i said earlier I'm new to this. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place for a while loop instead of that if statement:

```
while usernamelength > 10:
      # ask for the username again
      # usernamelength = len(newUsername)
```

That way you'll just continue to prompt for the username until you're given something over 10 chars.

Comment: Sorry if i'm still missing something obvious, but It has worked a bit. It now always says that It's too long now though. Here's what i have now.

```username =input("Welcome! before we start, please enter your desired name.")
usernamelength = (len(username))
while usernamelength > 10:
    username =input("Name too long. Please enter a name that is shorter then 10 characters.")
else:
    print("Hello, %s. Placeholder text" % username)
```

Comment: Edit: solved :) Thanks!